# Multiple Arguments to a Grep Command

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I am trying to use grep like this:

```
echo "$word" | grep [[\d+]&&[a-z]&&[A-Z]&&[\W]];
```

where word contains a password having alphanumeric and special characters. I want to check if grep can fetch it all but this somehow doesn't work. Can anybody explain this in context of Regular expression. Like what I am trying and what is happening?

Comment: Can you include some examples where `grep` should output, and others that should not be in the output?

Comment: You need to quote the argument to grep, otherwise bash interprets the special characters. Also, `&` has no meaning in grep, double or not.

Comment: What are you doing? Validating a password? Extracting alphanumeric words from large text?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to validate the `word` to contain all of lower alphabet, upper alphabet, digit, and a special character, please try something like:

```
word="+abc123DEF"
grep -P '^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*\W)' <<< "$word" && echo "ok"
```

It makes a use of a positive lookahead assertion enabled by `-P` (PCRE) option.